# using node.js in making website

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm starting to use Node.js.I install  the latest version of Express"3.4.1, and began to code.but as soon as I try sending parameters except /, I get error..
i have this file index.js

```
 exports.speakers = function(req, res){
    var myArtwork = [];
    var myArtists = [];

    myArtists = appdata.speakers;
    appdata.speakers.forEach(function(item)
    {
        myArtwork = myArtwork.concat(item.artwork);
});
  res.render('speakers', { 
    title: 'Speakers' ,
    artwork: myArtwork,
    artists: myArtists,
    page: 'artistList'
  });
};
```

now i want to get the id like in app.js i am using this app.get('/speakers/:speakerid', routes.speakers); but i dont knw how to use exports in index,js.. plz help me for this

Comment: which kind of error do you faced

Comment: Please let us know the error you are getting...

Comment: Install express 4.x,  many things have changed since express 4 was launched.

Comment: the same content was display when i click on link of any post... speakerid is used to get the particular id to be shown.. bt when i click on particular link then the same content is shown.by this.app.get('/speakers', routes.speakers);

Comment: how to get the speakersid using exports??

Answer (score 0):

You want to know how to get the id using exports?
like this?

```
req.params.speakerid
```